# Unable to add DNS into the ignore host Network Proxy Preferences Linux

Tags: linux, dns, unix, proxy, gnome

I have internal DNS ( let say it example.com ),
I’m unable to add this DNS into the ignore host Network Proxy Preferences, due to the Amazon Linux AWS workspaces key not writable. As a result, not able to access URL using web browser.
This DNS already added to the bash profile (~/.bash_profile ) , hence terminal access ok , but issue with web browser access.

Seems to be the changes are not being saved within the "ignored hosts" - "Network Proxy Preferences”. In my Linux AWS workspaces machine.
I have tried to add using dconf-editor , but changes not saving .

Below Steps also applied, but still having issue accessing DNS via Amazon workspace.

`$ export no_proxy=$no_proxy,example.com`

Edit local-custom-lock

`$ gsettings get org.gnome.system.proxy ignore-hosts | tee ~/gsettings-org.gnome.system.proxy-ignore-hosts.backup`

`$ sudo sed -i -e '/ignore-hosts/ s/^#*/#/' /etc/dconf/db/site.d/locks/local-custom-lock`

`$ sudo dconf update`

Adjust ignored hosts with script.

add-ignored-hosts.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
SCHEMA="org.gnome.system.proxy"
KEY="ignore-hosts"
STATUS=$(gsettings get ${SCHEMA} ${KEY})
echo "${STATUS}" > ~/gsettings-org.gnome.system.proxy-ignore-hosts.backup
if [[ $STATUS == *"'example.com'"* ]]; then
echo " example.com is already in the list!"
else gsettings set ${SCHEMA} ${KEY} "${STATUS%]*}, 'example.com']"
echo "Added example.com to the list."
fi
```

```
$ ./add-ignored-hosts.sh
The key is not writable
Added example.com to the list.
```